# How to call a different post to a different controller in Rails Functional Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

I want to make a post request to a different controller inside my functional test which is intended for a particular controller. However the post method in ActiveController class just takes the method to be called, it doesn't take the controller name to be called. Any ideas how to invoke a different controller?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to call a separate controller in a functional test? There might be a better way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: so the functionality I'm trying to test involves two controllers. Should I use an integration test instead of a functional test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create tests for controllers using [ActiveSupport::TestCase](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html), you can set which controller to test when you don't want it inferred.

So you could add another class to your test for the current controller, set the controller to test against within the new class, and implement your test cases.

You didn't provide code so I can't provide a coded solution but here's a blog post regarding testing all methods on controller under RSpec: http://blog.wolfman.com/articles/2007/7/28/rspec-testing-all-actions-of-a-controller

[Personally, I moved away from RSpec/TestUnit for controller tests beyond route checks and fuzzy testing.  I much prefer integration testing (e.g. Cucumber) for something that involves multiple parts of the system.]

Comment: Current docs for TestCase (the link above was a third party site and now dead) https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html