# In a Rails controller test, how to access a different controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, controller, functional-testing

In a functional test, I want to call an action in another controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a different post to a different controller in Rails Functional Test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815817/how-to-call-a-different-post-to-a-different-controller-in-rails-functional-test)

Answer (score 13):

You have to *set the `@controller` instance variable* to the controller that should be used.

Example usage in a test helper method (of course you don't need to use it in a helper method - you can use it right in your test method):

```
def login(user_name='user', password='asdfasdf')

    # save the current controller
    old_controller = @controller

    # use the login controller
    @controller = LoginController.new       # <---

    # perform the actual login
    post :login, user_login: user_name, user_password: password
    assert_redirected_to controller: 'welcome', action: 'index'

    # check the users's values in the session
    assert_not_nil session[:user]

    assert_equal session[:user], User.find_by_login('user')

    # restore the original controller
    @controller = old_controller

end
```

Answered by Jonathan Weiss, in 2006 on ruby-forum: [post() to other controller in functional test?](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/63191)

It should be noted that, for the most part (probably >99.9% of the time), one should use integration tests (aka feature tests) for testing inter-controller behaviour.